# Some devices can't connect through ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet

My question is possibly related to this question: [Ethernet cable too long?](https://superuser.com/questions/775034/ethernet-cable-too-long)

I have ethernet cable installed and am able to connect an Xbox One and detect a signal; Xbox diagnostics work fine and the Xbox is detected by the router, and normal network things can happen with the Xbox connected, all services available etc.

However, other devices do not connect through the same cable; no internet connection, no link lights.  I have this problem with multiple devices connecting to the same cable (Apple-TV, Dell PC, Belkin Router).  I would have thought that it was the wrong connection except that the Xbox One does connect and the connection is entirely dependent on the attachment through that cable and the MAC address is the wired MAC address of the Xbox.

My questions are:

1. is this an indication that I should purchase a signal booster for the connection?  I doubt that the length is more than 100m, but can't tell because it is in the construction.
2. are there additional diagnostics that should be performed?  I don't have a cable tester and would rather not have to purchase one, if there is a program that can read the signal from a computer I would be much happier with that.

Note that this is my first question on this exchange.  I hope that this is on topic.  After much searching I was unable to find other examples of this kind of problem, but perhaps was not searching with the correct keywords.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: Length seems unlikely.  Can you provide details on what router you have at the other end of the cable?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this.

I was somewhat convinced that this wouldn't be the way that low signal strength would appear but had trouble ruling out other things because the Xbox connected.

After some obsessing about it, I decided to pull the cover off of the wall and see what was happening.

The 1A (green stripe) connector was off.  Somehow an Xbox can connect and get all services while missing a connection.